# solr Edismax parser qf parameter behavior weird?

Tags: solr

I am new to solr, tried to use the Edismax parser which intended to be more convenient.

I have two small problems.
1. According to the tutorial, we can use a combination of q & qf parameter:

```
"params": {
  "mm": "3",
  "q": "distributed system solr",
  "defType": "dismax",
  "indent": "true",
  "qf": "id",
  "fl": "id,score",
  "rows": "100",
  "wt": "json",
  "_": "1438877562378"
}
```

but if so, there is no result at all. why this happens?

2. I moved to the q.alt field.

`"params": {
      "mm": "3",
      "defType": "dismax",
      "q.alt": "distributed system solr",
      "indent": "true",
      "qf": "id",
      "fl": "id,score",
      "rows": "100",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1438877657837"
    }
  },`

As I understand, it should do a query only on the qf : id field. But as the result shows, I think it also queried in the data content or data stream for the "q" field to create the score. I may misunderstand some point, but want know how the score is generated. It should only do the query on the id field right?

Comment: Can you share your solrcongfig.xml select handler?

Comment: Add debugQuery to your query (you can do this easily in the admin query interface), which will allow you to see which fields are being queried. `qf` tells the dismax handler which fields it should search, so the first query searches for all three terms of "distributed system solr" in a field named `id` - this seems to be weird content to have in an `id` field. You probably should use `edismax` instead of `dismax` if you intended to use the edismax parser.

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes, I tried edismax, this time, I see if I set the search field in id, and search parameter in q,  for example, if q ='2015-06-10T00:00:00Z' id='date' there is result. But if q='2015-06-10T', there is no result, I mean it's something does not support fuzzy match or regex match, quite weird

Comment: If you're querying a date field, you'll have to use the proper syntax if you want to query for all values on a specific date. You can't just use a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying a qf (query field) == id.  are you sure that the docs have matching data in the ID fields? probably not.  I would suggest adding more fields in the qf